# How to stop Woocommerce Add to Cart redirecting to Product Pages

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Because of a way a customer wanted their products displayed I've used `woocommerce` shortcode to display products. When Add to Cart is clicked, I didn't want the customer to leave the page but stay on that page until they'd finished ordering.

I have used this code in my Child Theme `functions.php` file and it successfully stopped the redirection and kept the customer on the page they were on.

```
//Prevent shortcode [product_page] redirecting to the actual product's page after add to cart
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_redirect', 'wp_get_referer' );
```

BUT after I added a plugin that gave minimum or maximum quantities and the quantity is below the minimum the Add to Cart redirects to the product page again whenever a product is below the minimum.

I'm not great on `php` and am not sure what I need to put in the functions.php file to stop this happening.

Any suggestions much appreciated.

Comment: Unchecked the stock management for those products and you can disabled ore removed the Product detail link. Moreover share your code so can guide in better way.

Comment: The products are variable products and have no stock management checked on them.  Sorry to be ignorant, I'm more of a designer than developer so what code should I share. Here is the site if you want to look at how it is working.  https://wholesalesoap.com.au/wordpress/honey-soaps/ if you click on eg soap logs and only add 1 to the cart you will see the redirection.

Comment: Do you want only product catalog which just displayed the products ?

Comment: No I want them to be able to purchase but the customer has alot of requirements on her products with minimum quantities, variable products and displaying products in a certain way so had to do a lot of workarounds with woocommerce. So I just need a filter I suppose for the functions.php file to stop the add to cart redirection to product page when people choose a quantity below the minimum....

Comment: What's the plugin that you said is causing this?

Comment: The plugin I'm using is Min and Max Quantity for WooCommerce by BeRocket.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe other plugins are adding filter to the cart redirect as well. You could try to set your own filter's priority to a big number so that it's executed after the other filters.

```
add_filter('','',50); //or even a bigger number
```

Comment: Did you mean to add a number to the current code I'm using (sorry not great with hooks and filters). I tried this but it's still redirecting to another page. I feel like I need to target that particular plugin but I'm not sure how to do this....
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_redirect', 'wp_get_referer', 100 );

Comment: The correct way about going about this is using the ajax request. Try turning on this setting and comment out your filter. This may work since that seems to be an archive products page: WooCommerce->Settings->Products->General->Enable Ajax add to cart buttons on archives

Comment: This doesn't work. I've enabled Ajax and commented out the filter but it goes to the product page still.

Comment: did you uncheck the setting above where it says Redirect to cart after successful addition?

Comment: Oh I see what's going on...so only happens for unsuccessful cart addition right? The reason is that the filter is only used when the item is added successfully. The default variable product outputs the product shop url as the form action's url. So if not redirecting, it stays on the form submission page. So going with the redirect route requires you to build custom forms or modify the templates for these product forms. You definitely want to use ajax for this. I'd look for a plugin that does this for you. Also your plugin should display some info about the min/max restriction..

Comment: Ok thanks for looking into it for me. I will see if I can find a better plugin with ajax.